# how to have two buttons in my view to same action method asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two submit buttons which call the same action method. How can I tell which of these buttons was clicked in the `formcollection` of the action method (without setting the value property of the buttons)?

HTML code for buttons:

```
<input type="submit" name="button" />
<input type="submit" name="button"  />
```

Action method as:

```
public ActionResult submitted(FormCollection form)
{
}
```

i know how to do if we have a value property, but I just want to try like this without value property. How can this be done?

thanks,
michaeld

Comment: Why would you not use the value property? Is there some reason you want to avoid using standard practices here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do, is intercept the click action to set a hidden form variable before the form is submitted, e.g.:

```
<script language="text/javascript">
    $("form input[submit]").click(function() {
        $("#buttonSelected").val("some unique value here");
    });
</script>
```

Where you might have a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="buttonSelected" name="buttonSelected" />
```

That way, you can then check the specific "buttonSelected" form value to figure out which button was pressed.

Comment: thanks Matthew, idea is nice , but how may i know which button is clicked in javascript?